# How to focus on a list element using the tab function and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a questionnaire for a client.  They want the active question that is on focus to be at 100% opacity while the other inactive questions are at 20% opacity.  Currently I have the page load, the questions dim to 20% opacity and the first question is at 100%.  When I am done with a question and tab to the next question, that active list element stays at 20% opacity until I actually click the list element and/or the input field. How do I make the field or list element active and 100% opacity.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<ul>

<li class="main" id="first-element" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <div class="question">This is my first question</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Answer">
</li>

<li class="main" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <div class="question">Second Question</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Second Answer">
</li>

<li class="main" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <div class="question">Third Question</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Third Answer">
</li>

</ul>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.main').fadeTo(1000, 0.2);
    $('li#first-element').fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
});

$('li.main').click(function() {
    // Make all list elements (except this) transparent
    $('li.main').not(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.2
    });
    // Make this opaque
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is a working solution on JSFiddle thanks to your help: https://jsfiddle.net/urfwap4n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `keyup` for this issue, maybe help you:

```
var hideshow = function(obj){
    $('li.main').not(obj).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.2
    });
    // Make this opaque
    $(obj).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    });
}

$('li.main').click(function() {
    hideshow(this);
});

$('li.main').on('keyup',function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 9) { //Enter keycode
        hideshow(this);
    } 
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/dpxz74zp/)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking to do.  Thank you. I'll post the updated fix in my original answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the function

```
$('li.main').click(function() { ...
```

try

```
$('li.main').on("focus", function() { ...
```

Also the on function optimised memory usage better than just using the "focus" function

Comment: Also, I noticed that you may need to change your selector from `li.main` to `li.main input` as strictly speaking you can't really focus on an li element, but rather the inputs it contains.

Comment: The selector is li.main because the whole list element should be highlighted including the input.  I tried $('li.main').on("focus", function() {... and when I click or tab to the next input it does not change the opacity at all.  I change the selector to li.main input and the first input changes to 0.2 opacity like the other inactive input fields.